# Custom hlines in mplfinance python

Tags: python, mplfinance

I am plotting four horizontal lines using the statement below.  For one of the lines I would like to use a different format (color and line style) than the other three lines.

```py
mpf.plot(df2,hlines=[aa,h,l,x82],type='candle',style='yahoo',volume=False,figsize=(9, 5),title=str(c[15]),addplot=b)
```

Would appreciate any assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [**the "using lines" tutorial**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/using_lines.ipynb) it is possible to pass a **`dict`** in for the hlines kwarg.  This allows you to specify the following attributes of the lines: `colors`, `linestyle`, `linewdiths` and `alpha`.  So, for example, given your code above:

```py
mpf.plot(df2,
         hlines=[aa,h,l,x82],
         type='candle',
         style='yahoo',
         volume=False,
         figsize=(9, 5),
         title=str(c[15]),
         addplot=b)
```

If you wanted all four hlines to be different you could do the following:

```py
mpf.plot(df2,
         hlines=dict(hlines=[aa,h,l,x82],
                     colors=['r','g','b','c'],
                     linestyle=['-','--','-.',':'],
                     linewidths=[2,4,6,8]),
         type='candle',
         style='yahoo',
         volume=False,
         figsize=(9, 5),
         title=str(c[15]),
         addplot=b)
```

If you wanted online one line to be different you could do something like this:

```py
mpf.plot(df2,
         hlines=dict(hlines=[aa,h,l,x82],
                     colors=['g','g','g','c'],
                     linestyle=['-','-','-',':'],
                     linewidths=[2,2,2,6]),
         type='candle',
         style='yahoo',
         volume=False,
         figsize=(9, 5),
         title=str(c[15]),
         addplot=b)
```

And, of course, if you wanted all four lines to be the same, you could do this:

```py
mpf.plot(df2,
         hlines=dict(hlines=[aa,h,l,x82],
                     colors='c',
                     linestyle='-',
                     linewidths=4),
         type='candle',
         style='yahoo',
         volume=False,
         figsize=(9, 5),
         title=str(c[15]),
         addplot=b)
```